# The drop sentence doesn't work with variables created with macro arrays SAS

Tags: sas, macros

I am trying to run the following code, that calculates the slope of each variables' timeseries.
I need to drop the variables created with an array, because I use the same logic for other functions.
Nevertheless the output data keeps the variables `ys_new&i._:` and I get the warning: ***The variable 'ys_new3_:'n in the DROP, KEEP, or RENAME list has never been referenced***.
I think the iterator is evaluated to 3 in the `%do %while` block.
If someone can help me, I will really apreciated it.

```
DATA HAVE;
INPUT ID N_TRX_M0-N_TRX_M12 TRANSACTION_AMT_M0-TRANSACTION_AMT_M12;
DATALINES;
1 3 6 3 3 7 8 6 10 5 5 8 7 7 379866 856839 307909 239980 767545 511806 603781 948936 566114 402214 844657 2197164 817390
2 51 56 55 73 48 57 54 53 55 52 49 72 53 6439314 7367157 4614827 9465017 3776064 3661525 7870605 3971889 4919128 10024385 4660264 7748467 7339863
3 5 . . . . . . . . . . . . 232165 . . . . . . . . . . . .
;
RUN;

%Macro slope(variables)/parmbuff;
    %let i = 1;
    /* Get  the  first  Parameter */
    %let parm_&i = %scan(&syspbuff,&i,%str( %(, %)));
    
    %do %while (%str(&&parm_&i.) ne %str());

        array ys&i(12) &&parm_&i.._M12 - &&parm_&i.._M1;
        array ys_new&i._[12];
        
/*      Corre los valores missing*/
        k = 1;
        do j = 1 to 12;
            if not(missing(ys&i(j))) then do;
                ys_new&i._[k] = ys&i[j];
                k + 1;
            end;
        end;

        nonmissing = n(of ys_new&i._{*});

        xbar = (nonmissing + 1)/2;

        if nonmissing ge 2 then do;                     
            ybar = mean(of ys&i(*));
            
            cov = 0;
            varx = 0;

            do m=1 to nonmissing;
                cov=sum(cov, (m-xbar)*(ys_new&i._(m)-ybar));
                varx=sum(varx, (m-xbar)**2);
            end;

            slope_&&parm_&i. = cov/varx;
        end;            
        %let i = %eval(&i+1);
    /* Get  next  parm */
    %let  parm_&i =  %scan(&syspbuff ,&i, %str( %(, %)));
    %end;
    drop ys_new&i._: k j m nonmissing ybar xbar cov varx;
%mend;

%let var_slope = 
    N_TRX,
    TRANSACTION_AMT
;

DATA FEATURES;
    SET HAVE;
    %slope(&var_slope)
RUN;
```

Comment: If you don't need the array can you use a temporary array instead? Add `_temporary_` after the declaration?

Comment: Can you explain what is the purpose of the code?  Are you calculating some statistic? If you explain what statistic is it perhaps someone can show you the SAS function of procedure that calculates it directly without the need to do it "by hand".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. `&i` is 3 after it exits the `do` loop leading to the `drop` statement giving a warning that `ys_new3_:` does not exist. Instead, consider using a temporary array to avoid the drop statement altogether:

```
array ys_new&i._[12] _TEMPORARY_;
```

Comment: You need to also add `call missing(of ys_new&i._[*]);` before the `do j` loop because temporary arrays are retained, so values set by earlier observations will bleed over to the new observations. For your example input data that is going to yield different values for the slope variables in the third observation.

Comment: I did not realize temporary arrays are automatically retained. That is great information.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to generate the DROP statement before the macro has a chance to change the value of the macro variable I .

```
array ys&i(12) &&parm_&i.._M12 - &&parm_&i.._M1;
array ys_new&i._[12];
drop ys_new&i._: k j m nonmissing ybar xbar cov varx;
```

You could use a _TEMPORARY_ array instead, but then you need to remember to clear the values on each iteration of the data step.

```
array ys_new&i._[12] _temporary_;
call missing(of ys_new&i._[*]);
```

Then you can leave the DROP statement at the end if you want.

```
drop k j m nonmissing ybar xbar cov varx;
```